# How to create inline node-add forms using a block with content type names

Tags: panels, javascript

The following page setup is needed:
A block (at the left, see image) with links to node-add forms, which open inline (the area at the right) in the current page.

The reason why the form needs to appear inline, is that this page is part of a group and the layout of the group and group menu and all must stay the same

I tried to create a Panel page variant for the node add form, but the minipanels that I use in node panels are not available there.

I thought about using an iframe, but that is not recommended generally, especially not for mobile use.

I can't find modules that are specifically suitable for this purpose, but I might have missed some.

What way could I accomplish this setup using javascript/jquery ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels is definitely the way to go here.

1. Using Page Manager set up a URL with an argument, like `mypath/%node-type`
2. Set the argument to be `Node add form: content type`
3. In the content area you can rearrange the form how you like or just add the whole node creation form by using the elements under **form** in the add content screen
4. Make either a custom pane or a menu of links that point to the various node types:

   - `mypath/article`
   - `mypath/event`
   - `mypath/document`
   - `mypath/video`